# Is there an elegant way to attach a single event handler to all the preview mouse events in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, user-interface

I am writing a WPF behavior that is supposed to block all mouse events that occur when the mouse is not inside a specific square. I wanted the behavior to attach a PreviewMouse*** event handler that checks the mouse position and sets Handled=true if the mouse is not inside the specific square. The problem is that there are a lot of different mouse events and I prefer that my code be elegant and clean. Is there a way to catch all preview mouse events in one elegant line?
Thnx,

Comment: A simple way of making that would be to create an attached property for UIElement that does reflection on events, filter on those containing "Preview" in the name, and then suscribe it with the handler name passed in the attached property. It is not ultra safe but that is the only automated solution I could think of.

Comment: There are about 6-7 events with PreviewMouse***, I would just add the same event handler to all of them instead of using some over complicated solution to do this. You'll end up writing at least the same amount of code and which would be slightly harder to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is use reflection to attach to all events containing "PreviewMouse" in their name. To achieve that you can simply create an extension method for UIElement and implement it like this

```
public static class UIElementExtensions
{
    public static void HandleAllPreviewMouse(this UIElement uiElement, RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        var elementType = uiElement.GetType();

        foreach (var eventInfo in elementType.GetEvents().Where(ei => ei.Name.Contains("PreviewMouse")))
        {
            var specificHandler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, handler.Method);
            eventInfo.AddEventHandler(uiElement, specificHandler);
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your Window code behind attach your handling code to your root layout Grid (or whavetever parent element you want to hook) using the extension

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var handler = new RoutedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Preview event fired");

        // Uncomment if you want to block event propagation
        //e.Handled = true;
    });

    this.LayoutRoot.HandleAllPreviewMouse(handler);
}
```

This solution is a one-liner solution to your issue but keep in mind it is not extra clean, especially on the part where events are filtered based on their name. But you can surely work it a bit to make it better.

Comment: Thnx for the solution. Like you have said, it is not exactly elegant in the sense that it relies on event names but that could easily be corrected by holding a static list of EventInfo objects looping over them instead of the names. Another problem is that the handler does not pass the more specific mouse event arguments which is required in order for the handler to decide if to block evet propagation. Nevertheless, it is the cleanest solution I can expect unless there is some sort of WPF Magic trick I am not aware of...

Comment: Well you could tweak this solution a bit and provide few specific handlers (like mouse specific one) that would match depending on the EventInfo.EventHandlerType and provide a default one for the other ones (routed event handler).

Answer (score 2):

**PreviewMouse** events are **tunnelling events** so they tunnel from root element to the actual sender. So, you can hook the `PreviewMouse*** event handler` on root element if you don't want to attach explicitly to all child elements.

And in handler you can check `e.OriginalSource` to get control which actually raises that event and can code accordingly.

```
<Grid PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Handler">
   <Button/>
   <TextBox/>
   <TextBlock/>
   <AnotherControl/>
</Grid>
```

---

**Update for comment**:

> What I am looking for is a single C# line of code that attaches a
>   single event handler to many different mouse events on the same
>   element (PreviewMouseDown, PreviewMouseUp, PreviewLeftMouseDown,
>   PreviewLeftMouseUp, PreviewMouseWheel...). Instead of attaching the
>   same handler to each event specifically, I would like to attach it to
>   all of them at once.

I think you are complicating things here just to avoid some lines of code. Those events are independent of each other, so one or other way you have to assign a handler to it (may be with reflection as proposed in other answer). But, I don't think it's a nice approach to do that considering reflection is bit slower. Moreover, with that approach you will end up having same lines of code.

If lines of code is a concern, then you can encapsulate in a method and pass on common handler to it and hook the handler to interested events.

```
    private void HookPreviewMouseEvents(MouseButtonEventHandler handler)
    {
        PreviewMouseDown += handler;
        PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += handler;
        PreviewMouseUp += handler;
    }
```

Comment: The OP was asking how to attach to ALL preview events in the most elegant way not how to handle them.

Comment: @Ucodia - That's what I mentioned that, attach it at root element instead of attaching it for all child elements. Handling part I mentioned just in case required by him. May be is should remove the additional part if not required.

Comment: Well it sounded to me that the OP was aware of this solution but wanted to avoid that with an automatic solution.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by automatic? As per OP - `Is there a way to catch all preview mouse events in one elegant line?`. May be I will wait for OP's feedback here and will update the answer in case OP needs something else.

Comment: He wanted a one liner in C# or XAML with which he could suscribre to all "PreviewXXX" events.

Comment: I agreed with what Ucodia wrote. The question was not how to catch a single event on all elements, but how to catch all the mouse events with a single event handler.Also, since I am doing this inside a behavior, it can't be done in XAML. What I am looking for is a single C# line of code that attaches a single event handler to many different mouse events on the same element (PreviewMouseDown, PreviewMouseUp, PreviewLeftMouseDown, PreviewLeftMouseUp, PreviewMouseWheel...). Instead of attaching the same handler to each event specifically, I would like to attach it to all of them at once.

Comment: @Kobi - If I have to give my opinion, I think you are complicating things here because one or other way you have to attach handler to all those events. So you will end up writing same number of lines anyhow. Rest definitely is your call. Was just trying to assist. Anyhow thanks for downvote. Have a nice day..!! :)

Comment: @Rohit, you are correct. I am not trying to bend WPF to save me from writing some extra lines of code. (Writing this question takes more lines of code... so laziness is not an issue ;-)  ). It just seems to me that a scenario where one may want to have a single logic to handle all mouse events, may be common enough for WPF to have some sort of solution. Of course attaching all the event handlers is a viable solution, I just wanted to see if there is a more elegant solution. I agree that using reflection here is an overkill.

Comment: @Kobi - No issues mate..!!